# Angular 2 - Custom component - Pass arguments as "divs" instead of "attributes"?

Tags: angular, templates, parameters

I found this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xFBllK?p=preview

it's an accordion... but there is a parameter for the title as an attribute

how do I change that component so that I can add my own html in the template for the title (and not just pass the title as a parameter)?

in file app.component.ts, how do I change the implementation of the accordion to turn this

```
<tp-accordion-group>
  <tp-accordion [title]="some title">
    ...
  </tp-accordion>
</tp-accordion-group>
...
```

into  this

```
<tp-accordion-group>
  <tp-accordion>
    <div title><some complex fancy html content>some title<...></div>
    <div body>...</div>
  </tp-accordion>
  ...
</tp-accordion-group>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer is TRANSCLUSION

example here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content